# How to create snack.expo audio player

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am currently working on a snack.expo music app using expo-av. I am have trouble with the sound playing part.

**Working**

- swipe for next/prev song(only changes image, name, artist)
- use next/prev button(only changes image, name, artist)
- Playing correct sound

**Help Needed**

- pausing and playing sound
- adding functionality to bottom buttons
- implementing slider

I need to grab sound data from data.js and I need to play it based on which image is shown on screen. Right now there are just sample sounds and images.

[snack link](https://snack.expo.dev/@d99/d99musicapp-1) (almost full code)

Comment: @James Z - little help please

Comment: @Community I have provided a snack.expo link to the code